# Why do I still get some voltage at the load when the regulator supposedly is turned off?

Tags: ldo, leakage-current

As I rolled my simpleified (removed the overload protection circuit) [home-built PMOS LDO](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/144849/how-to-test-and-rate-a-home-built-low-dropout-regulator) circuit on a breadboard, I found out something strange is going on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTcO21.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now what is going on? Why am I seeing 0.01 V across my 1 kΩ load? Also, why is the sampling voltage divider emitting 0.04 V? Or is it because of the OPA2134 amplifier? Did I get a fake one from the Shenzhen supplier?

Am I treading the waters of leakage currents of semiconductors?

Answer (score 1):

Both the [IRF4905](http://www.redrok.com/MOSFET_IRF4905_-55V_-74A_20mO_Vth-4.0_TO-220.pdf)
and the [2N7002](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/2N/2N7000.pdf) have a non-zero drain to source current when the gate to source potential is zero. For the IRF4095 the drain to source leakage current is 25 uA with a VDS=-55 V. 25 uA across the output load resistance of 903 Ohms (1 k || 9.4 k) gives 23 mV. This is reasonably similar to the 10 mV you measure, especially since the VDS is different than the datasheet and the VGS is not precisely 0. 
I can't explain why the node of the sampling divider is reading 0.04 V. I would expect that node to be 1/2 Vout (the op-amp has an input bias current of 5 pA).

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of that 1uF capacitor on the op-amp output. It's probably oscillating internally at a few tens of kHz.

Comment: Without a scope, how to tell if it is actually oscillating?